# How to start another activity by intent and not showing anything

Tags: android, android-intent

Inside my MainActivity class:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpECf.jpg)

Inside my MessagesActivity class
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENoHs.jpg)

I simply want when I click on the messages button, it will lead me to another activity and another user interface which has nothing on it.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text, in the question itself.

Comment: The easy way is you can set "onClick" attribute from XML layout file. set "onClick" for the button you want to click

Comment: @HuyN That is what I did but the program still crashes

Comment: @FionaH try my answer

Comment: what is the errors showing on your logical?

Answer (score 0):

Take button one button in actvity_main.xml

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/msg"
    android:text="Message"
    />
```

In your main activity class:

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
  Button msg;



  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     msg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.msg);
     msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext,MessageActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
     }
    });
  }
}
```

and please add your MessageActivity in mainifest

Comment: add following line on manifest of messages activity manifest: <activity android:name="MessagesActivity" >
    </activity> Is that what you mean

Comment: @FionaH you try my code?, yes in manifest you have to add <activity android:name="MessagesActivity" > </activity>

Comment: @FionaH if it is work for you then please accept my answer